# iptables forwards traffic, but does not receive responses

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, iptables

So I'm currently trying to use a raspberry pi as a sort of range extender where you connect wlan0 to an access point, and the hostapd AP setup on the interface wap0 routes all traffic through wlan0. The chain would look like this:

```
    Wireless Client---> wap0 AP ---> wlan0 ---> Network Gateway ---> Internet
```

I currently have my iptables rules setup as follows:

```
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i wap0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A POSTROUTING ACCEPT
    -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

ip_forward is also set to 1

What I've found after looking at some tcpdumps is that the outgoing traffic from wap0 to wlan0 does in fact get forwarded, but I never receive any responses to this traffic on wlan0. If the traffic originates from the raspberry pi (like a ping to www.google.com), I get a response. However any traffic coming from a client connected to wap0 and routed through wlan0 gets no response.

It is worth noting, however, that even when I flush all of the ip rules and fire up a tcpdump session on wlan0, I can still see traffic from wap0 being routed to the interface.

wap0 is setup to put all of its clients on the 192.168.8.0/24 subnet, and the subnet of the network wlan0 is connected to is 10.118.30.0/24. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?